# Spring boot: Why use OncePerRequestFilter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a class called `JwtTokenAuthorizationOncePerRequestFilter` where it extends `OncePerRequestFilter`

However, I'm having issue when I login, then after some usage of the web app

I get "JWT_TOKEN_DOES_NOT_START_WITH_BEARER_STRING" always

See code below:

```
package com.sbc.cpex.security.jwt;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException;

@Component
public class JwtTokenAuthorizationOncePerRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtInMemoryUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Value("${jwt.http.request.header}")
    private String tokenHeader;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.debug("Authentication Request For '{}'", request.getRequestURL());

        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader(this.tokenHeader);

        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;
        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                logger.error("JWT_TOKEN_UNABLE_TO_GET_USERNAME", e);
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                logger.warn("JWT_TOKEN_EXPIRED", e);
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("JWT_TOKEN_DOES_NOT_START_WITH_BEARER_STRING");
        }

        logger.debug("JWT_TOKEN_USERNAME_VALUE '{}'", username);
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

            UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtInMemoryUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Is it possible for me to just trigger this class when logging in? And not when accepting other requests

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Well, you get that "warning" because you have this line, if someone does not send in a bearer token:

```
 logger.warn("JWT_TOKEN_DOES_NOT_START_WITH_BEARER_STRING");
```

As I assume you are potentially protecting all your URLs in your application, you will need to have your JWTFilter work for every URL.

Comment: If I remove this line, will it have any impact on the security? Should I constantly be warned that the requestTokenHeader does not start with "Bearer ". Or this is quite harmless. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Note that I'm sending requests to my endpoint using React. And its in the frontend where I append the "Bearer " string

Comment: The line is just a log statement that gets triggered whenever someone does not send in a bearer token with a request. So the question is, why is there no bearer token coming in?

Comment: I think it only appends bearer token when login is triggered. But aside from that, all other requests does not come with bearer token.

Answer (score 0):

The logger only warns during login as request URL does not included bearer token yet. Succeeding URL calls will no longer show this warning message if you set session storage for token with bearer plus token generated during login createAuthenticationToken

Answer (score 0):

you are not passing token on "Authorization" header or this token that u are passing, does not begin with Bearer. Consider to put create generate token inside these method

Answer (score 0):

Because String username = null;
and nowhere username is assigned with value from request.
You need to get JSONObject from HttpServletRequest request and parse it to get username.